# How to compute $d^2y$?

Tags: calculus

Let 
$$
\begin{cases} x = \ln \sqrt{1+t^2}, \\ y = \arctan t. \end{cases}
$$

How to compute $d^2y$?

My partial solution: we have 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ (\arctan t)' }{(\ln \sqrt{1+t^2})'} = \frac{\frac{1}{(1+t^2)}}{\frac{2t}{2\sqrt{1+t^2}}} = \frac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\frac{1}{e^x\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}.
$$
Therefore
$$
dy = \frac{1}{e^x\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx.
$$
Is this correct? How to compute $d^2 y$? Thank you very much.

Edit: $$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ (\arctan t)' }{(\ln \sqrt{1+t^2})'} = \frac{\frac{1}{(1+t^2)}}{\frac{2t}{2(1+t^2)}} = \frac{1}{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by $d^2 y$?

Comment: In all my time I have never seen a problem to find $d^2y$. Maybe taking the second derivative and ending up with $$d^2y = \text{blah} \,dx^2$$.

Comment: I think that the derivative of $x=\log(\sqrt{1+t^2})$ wrt to $t$ is not what you wrote.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yes, thank you very much.

Comment: @Chinny84, yes, thank you very much.

Comment: You mean $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from @Chinny84's point

If $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} &=& \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx} \\
                      &=& \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{e^x\sqrt{e^{2x-1}}}=-\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}-\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{2x}-1)^{3/2}}$$

therefore
$$d^2y=-\left(\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}+\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{2x}-1)^{3/2}}\right)dx^2 =-\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx^2-\frac{e^{x}}{(e^{2x}-1)^{3/2}}dx^2$$